# react-admin pristine state after loading data via dataprovider

Tags: react-admin

I've got an issue due to a timing issue with react-admin, that i'm looking for a little help on.

The situation is where user A creates a resource, and user B, on a different PC, then goes to list and edit that resource.

For user B, the list page loads the full dataset of 10 resources, then the edit page re-loads the single resource that is being edited.

However, the specific process on the edit page seems to be:

1. Render page
2. Render resource cached from the list page
3. Request the single resource from the API
4. Populate the edit form with the updated values from the API
5. Set the form to dirty

That last point is critical, since I have an action button that is only enabled if the form is pristine, so the user has to save any changes before triggering the action.

But in this case, the list view and the edit view seem to return the same data for the resource, so I'm not sure why the form is being set to dirty.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I hope it helps you save some time. I recently upgraded React Admin version from 3.5.3 to 3.6.0. I noticed that the Save button is now sometimes disabled unexpectedly, and inconsistently. For example, I may navigate to the edit view of a resource by clicking a link and the Save button is enabled, but if I refresh the page, the Save button is disabled. Apparently, the Save button is supposed to be disabled when the form is pristine. So between 3.5.3 and 3.6.0, it seems that some changes were made to either the pristine handling or the Save button's reaction to pristine, and it is not working consistently.

I see there is a new issue opened three days ago regarding overriding the Save button behavior, wrt pristine. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4913 . So, it seems the dust hasn't settled on this behavior. Perhaps a bug will be found.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated to 3.6.0 as well. The pristine thing is still an issue I think, but I've not hammered out exactly what's happening. I've also got two save buttons - save and return to list, or save and continue editing this resource. The second one still seems to think the form is not pristine even after saving.

Comment: I don't supposed you know how pristine is actually *set* do you? I've not been able to find this yet. Not sure if it's embedded within another library?

Comment: I have not had to get into the details of pristine yet. RA uses React Final Form, and a quick look at the code indicates that RA uses subscriptions to receive events like changes in pristine from RFF.

Comment: Same here. One trick is to give it a default value, for example <TextInput source="myField" defaultValue = "" />